# How to create a rotation animation using shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, animations

I am looking for a script that creates a rotation animation using character `/`,`-`, `|` and `\`.

If you continuously switch between these characters it should look like its rotating. How to make this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use that script:

```
#!/bin/bash

chars="/-\|"

while :; do
  for (( i=0; i<${#chars}; i++ )); do
    sleep 0.5
    echo -en "${chars:$i:1}" "\r"
  done
done
```

The `while` loop runs infinite. The `for` loop runs trough each character of the string given in `$chars`. `echo` prints the character, with a carriage return `\r`, but without linebreak `-n`. `-e` forces echo to interpret escape sequences such as `\r`.
There's a delay of 0.5 seconds between each change.

Comment: Clever, +1, but why not `printf "%s\r" "${chars:$i:1}"`?

Comment: @terdon first thought was `echo`... but of course `printf` works too. ^^

Comment: You can try it without the for loop: `chars="/-\|"; while sleep 0.5; do echo -en "${chars:$(( i=(i+1) % ${#chars} )):1}" "\r"; done`

Comment: The `offset` and `length` parts of `${var:offset:length}` are already arithmetic expressions, so we can remove some of the syntax: `echo -en "${chars: i = (i + 1) % ${#chars} : 1}"`

Answer (score 22):

Here's an example using `\b`, which tells the terminal emulator to move the cursor one column to the left, in order to keep overwriting the same character over and over.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

spinner() {
    local i sp n
    sp='/-\|'
    n=${#sp}
    printf ' '
    while sleep 0.1; do
        printf "%s\b" "${sp:i++%n:1}"
    done
}

printf 'Doing important work '
spinner &

sleep 10  # sleeping for 10 seconds is important work

kill "$!" # kill the spinner
printf '\n'
```

See [BashFAQ 34](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/034) for more.

Comment: Great code. I would make one small modification, though. After running `spinner &`, I would store the pid in a local variable `spinner_pid=$!` and then replace the kill call with `kill $spinner_pid &>/dev/null`

Comment: I would like to add `tput civis #hide cursor` and `tput cnorm #show cursor`

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't explicitly ask for bash, a little plug for the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/), where this can be solved beautifully IMO:

```
set -l symbols ◷ ◶ ◵ ◴
while sleep 0.5
    echo -e -n "\b$symbols[1]"
    set -l symbols $symbols[2..-1] $symbols[1]
end
```

In this case, `symbols` is an array variable, and the contents if it are rotated/shifted, because `$symbols[2..-1]` are all entries but the first.

Answer (score 1):

very minimal way of writing using `printf`

```
sh-5.1$ while true ; do for i in \\ "|" / "-"; do printf "$i" ; sleep 0.1 ; printf "\b" ; done ; done
```